# Need SSO, RMM w/ Mac client GP management (printers etc) from one web portal

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, mac, single-sign-on, microsoft-office-365

I have a client that is looking for an all-in-one solution to manage users and computers.  Preferable in the cloud or SaaS.  They would like to be able to create/delete users from AD, integrate SSO for applications like Salesforce, Jira, Confluence and flowdock and Office 365.  If they create a new user, they would like it to automatically add the corresponding AD/GP permissions to the user and allow (as automatic as possible) accounts created at the various 3rd party sites.  They would also like this solution to add the capability to apply GP to the various Mac workstations, such as adding printers etc.  Remote monitoring and maintenance would also be a huge plus.

I have been looking everywhere and have tried about 8 different solutions so far, but haven't seen anything that does all of the above in one package.  Centrify is my next test, but I am certainly open to suggestions.  I don't usually have clients asking about SSO combined with RMM, so I am hoping we have some gurus here that could point me in the right direction.

Thanks!